# QGIS MapCanvas with Round Border

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt

I have a canvas within a QWidget (also tried QFrame) which uses a stylesheet:

```
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 10px;
```

The stylesheet looks great in the designer, but as soon as I put the canvas into the widget it does not adhere to the round frame design. The canvas overlaps the corners and remains rectangular.
If I increase the thickness/radius to 20px it is thick enough to prevent full overlap, but instead of getting a nice curve the inside of the corners become square due to the canvas overlap.

Basically I need a way to clip the canvas (QGraphicsView) with a rounded corner rectangle OR an inventive way to use a QGridLayout and overlap another widget to produce the rounded frame effect.